# How to get the phone state in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm using react native on and android project, and i'm in need of detect the call state of the actives calls of the android device, like incoming, connected, and etc.

I need the phone number of the incoming/outgoin cellphone too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show what you have done in order to implement it yourself?

Comment: I didn't anything yet..

Comment: I need any module that can help me to get the phone state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With react native, you can use [react-native-call-state](https://github.com/remobile/react-native-call-state) to check the state of the call, using like this:

```js
import React, { DeviceEventEmitter } from 'react-native'
import CallState from 'react-native-call-state';

componentWillMount() {
    CallState.startListener();
    this.subscription = DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('callStateUpdated', data => { console.warn(JSON.stringify(data)); });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    CallState.stopListener();
}
```

using java, you can use [TelephonyManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager), with a setup like:

```js
 public class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                handleRinging(incomingNumber);
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                handleOffHook();
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                handleIdle();
                break;
        }
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
    }
}
```

To get the phone number of a call, you can use [react-native-call-detection](https://github.com/priteshrnandgaonkar/react-native-call-detection), [here](https://medium.com/rnd-works-en/react-native-app-grabbing-the-incoming-calls-number-2fb00ad38639) you can have a full example of how to make it, from the beginning to the end.

Comment: ReferenceError: can't find variable: DeviceEventEmitter

Comment: make sure to import DeviceEventEmitter, `import React, { DeviceEventEmitter } from 'react-native'`

Comment: Thanks, bro you such a life saver.

Comment: Can you help to get the incoming call number..?

Comment: just a moment, i'm searching. and thanks for the right answer, i'm really in need of this haha

Comment: added it to the answer!