# Show Popup when Phone Rings in React native with expo

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I'm doing an android application with the expo framework. I want to make a popup when a voice call comes in and after call gets disconnected.

We can achieve this module using broadcast receiver(android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE). But I couldn't find any packages for react native with expo.

Can anyone help me to achieve this functionality?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the phone state in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61215268/how-to-get-the-phone-state-in-react-native)

Comment: @KirillNovikov Thank you for your comment. It is react native cli. Our project is based on react native with expo.

Comment: you can use third party libraries with expo https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/using-libraries/#using-third-party-libraries

Comment: We already searched it. No third party library to detect phone state in expo.

Comment: time to create it and share it with the community 